# Refactoring RxJava Observable concat code and error handling in functional way

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, observable, reactive-programming

How can I improve the code below and do error handling better here so that the code is more functional in nature.

```
final Observable<A> aResponse =a.update(52, 33, "759", obj);

final Observable<B> bResponse =b.fetch(52, 759);
Map map1 = new HashMap();
Map map2 = new HashMap();
```

Two rest api calls which return observables.The results are concatenated below map1 and map2 are populated.

`.concat` I am using concat here to combine the results of two apis. How can I use .zip() here or any other function.Can `flatMap()` be used here?

`.onErrorResumeNext` is used to continue execution of bResponse if aresponse throws error. How can I log error better if aResponse fails.Should I do it inside onErrorResumeNext.

`.subscribe` is used so that observer can see the items emitted by the concatenation of two observables.

 `onError` I am using onError to log error if bResponse fails. How can I do it better?

`onNext` In onNext I am getting Object typecasting it to B if it is an instanceOf B and then populating the items in map1 and map2. How can I right this in better way?

```
Observable.concat(aResponse, bResponse)
            .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<B>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<B> call(Throwable throwable) {
                    return bResponse;
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                 System.out.println("The response list after the fututres");
               }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    System.out.println("ERROR IN BRESPONSE");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Object o) {
                    if(o instanceof B)
                    {
                        ((B)o).getSomething().stream().forEach( s ->  {
                                   map1.put(s.getId(),s.getNumber());
                                   map2.put(s.getId(), s.getList());
                                });
                    }

                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `aResponse` needs to finish before you start observing `bResponse`, it better not to combine the observer chains into `Observable<Object>`.

```
aResponse
  .doOnError( error -> log.error( "Error on A stream", error )
  .onErrorResumeNext( Observable.empty() )
  .toCompletable()
  .andThen( bResponse )
  .subscribe( ... );
```

Essentially, the above chain monitors `aResponse` until it finishes, ignoring all elements. When `aResponse` is finished, you will then start observing `bResponse`, doing what you need to on `B` elements.

If you need to do something with `A` elements, you can add `doOnNext()` to the observer chain before `toCompletable()`.